# Importing a variable from another python script without running the module

Tags: python-3.x, variables

Ok, so first thing's first: I know how to import variables. That's not the problem.

```
from script import variable
```

I have a main script that has four child scripts. The main script has a GUI where I get the variables from the user. I use the import statement above to grab a variable from the main script, but when I do so, it runs the main script again.

That may be confusing, so here's an example:

main.py

```
from time import sleep
sleep = 10
maze = 'maze'
import script1
import script2
import script3
import script4
```

scripts 1-4

```
from time import sleep
from main import sleep
from main import maze
print(sleep)
print(maze)
```

I will try and write a better example, using all of the weird stuff that I have in the real script, but that is the basic outline of what is causing the problem.

This is what happens:

main.py runs

main.py is run again

script2.py runs

script3.py runs

script4.py runs

script1.py runs

Could anyone please help me with what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to mention that I can't add the "if **name** == **main**" to scripts 1-4 because they require certain things to happen.

Comment: You have to use the `if __name__=="__main__":` you can still make some of the script run so "certain things" happen.

Comment: That's true. Thx man!